# Spark RDD map internal object to Row

Tags: scala, apache-spark

My initial data from a CSV file is:

```
1 ,21658392713 ,21626890421 
1 ,21623461747 ,21626890421 
1 ,21623461747 ,21626890421
```

The data I have after a few transformations and grouping based on business logic is yields

```
scala> val sGrouped = grouped
sGrouped: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Iterable[(String,    
(Array[String], String))])] = ShuffledRDD[85] at groupBy at <console>:51

scala> sGrouped.foreach(f=>println(f))
(21626890421,CompactBuffer((21626890421, 
             ([Ljava.lang.String;@62ac8444,21626890421)), 
             (21626890421,([Ljava.lang.String;@59d80fe,21626890421)),       
             (21626890421,([Ljava.lang.String;@270042e8,21626890421)),
```

from this I want to get a map that yields something like the following format

```
[String, Row[String]]
```

so the data may look like:

```
[ 21626890421 , Row[(1 ,21658392713 ,21626890421)
              , (1 ,21623461747 ,21626890421)
              ,  (1 ,21623461747,21626890421)]]
```

I really appreciate any guidance on moving forward on this.

Comment: do you want a Row or just an Array would suffice ?

Comment: There is no such thing as `Row[String]`. And what exactly an `Array` from `(Array[String], String)` maps to your desired output?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, but I am not sure if this is an efficient way, any better approaches are appreciated, as this feels more like a hack.

```
scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
scala> val grouped = cToP.groupBy(_._1)
grouped: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Iterable[(String,
(Array[String], String))])] 

scala> val sGrouped = grouped.map(f => f._2.toList)
sGrouped: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[List[(String, (Array[String],    
String))]]


scala> val tGrouped = sGrouped.map(f =>f.map(_._2).map(c => 
Row(c._1(0), c._1(12), c._1(18))))
tGrouped: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[List[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]] = 
MapPartitionsRDD[42] a

scala> tGrouped.foreach(f => println(f))
```

yields

```
List([1,21658392713,21626890421], [1,21623461747,21626890421],    
[1,21623461747,21626890421])
scala> tGrouped.count()
res6: Long = 1
```

The answer I am getting is correct, and even the count is correct. However, I do not understand why the count is 1.

Comment: You yield Key/Value pairs, in your case only one pair as your output indicated. The value in your Key/Value pair is a list, but it is not that list you are counting.